# Center multiple variable-length divs within a parent div in CSS

Tags: css, html, center

I have three small divs that all appear within one parent div. The second (middle) div is variable size, as it will display text of slightly different lengths (month names).

How can I make the the centre div align to the centre of the parent div so that the first and third divs align correctly in the remaining space?

The CSS so far is here (but it doesn't work yet):

```
div.calendartitle {  //The parent
  display: block;
  width: 117px;
  height: 15px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  font-size: small;
  border-width: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}


div.calendartitleelement {  //The three sub-divs.
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 38px;
}
```

The HTML is generated in JS:

```
var html = "<div class='calendartitle'>";
  html += "<div class='calendartitleelement calendertitleclickable' onclick='buildCalendar(" + previousWeekStartingDay + "," + previousMonth + ");'>&#60;&#60;</div>";
  html += "<div class='calendartitleelement'>" + months[month] + "</div>";
  html += "<div class='calendartitleelement calendertitleclickable' onclick='buildCalendar(" + nextWeekStartingDay + "," + nextMonth + ");'>&#62;&#62;</div></div>";
  $("#calendardisplay").prepend(html);
```

Comment: the middle one isn't variable in width, since you've given it a width of 38px in your css. Furthermore, if the parent has a fixed width, and the left and right have a fixed width, the remaining width is also fixed. You might want to add a text-align: center; if you want to center the text inside the middle div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use float left with centering properties such as margin auto. Do this.

```
div.calendartitleelement {  //The three sub-divs.
  display: block;
  margin:0px auto;
  min-width: 38px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you give float to the div then margin:auto not works.So,auto & float is not simultaneously work.

Answer (score 0):

First put them in a wrapper div.

```
    <div class="wrapper">
<ul class="menu clearfix">
    <li class="item">test</li>
    <li class="item">test</li>
    <li class="item">test</li>
</ul>
</div>

<style>
.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper .menu {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline; /* ie6/7 hack for display inline, haslayout property */
}

.wrapper .menu li {
  float: left;
}

.clearfix:after {
    content:".";
    display:block;
    height:0;
    clear:both;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.clearfix {display:inline-block;}
/* Hide from IE Mac \*/
.clearfix {display:block;}
/* End hide from IE Mac */
</style>
```