# How to center multiple div tags when they are variable width?

Tags: html, css

I've seen some other posts on this but even using their method on my code doesn't seem to be working for me.  What am I doing wrong when trying to center these divs?

[This example works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/richcoleman/S4fTe/) (taken from [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705105/center-multiple-variable-length-divs-within-a-parent-div-in-css)).

[But this one (which is my code) doesn't behave the same and isn't centered properly.](http://jsfiddle.net/richcoleman/HNRyh/)

here is my code that is also [in my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/richcoleman/HNRyh/)

```
.pdf-pageimage-container {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 1px solid #EEE;
}


<div class="pdf-pageimage-container" style="position:relative;width:612px;height:792px;">
    <img style="width:612px;height:792px;" />
<div>
<div class="pdf-pageimage-container" style="position:relative;width:792px;height:612px;">
    <img style="width:792px;height:612px;" />
<div>
<div class="pdf-pageimage-container" style="position:relative;width:612px;height:792px;">
    <img style="width:612px;height:792px;" />
<div>
<div class="pdf-pageimage-container" style="position:relative;width:792px;height:612px;">
    <img style="width:792px;height:612px;" />
<div>
<div class="pdf-pageimage-container" style="position:relative;width:612px;height:792px;">
    <img style="width:612px;height:792px;" />
<div>
<div class="pdf-pageimage-container" style="position:relative;width:812px;height:792px;">
    <img style="width:812px;height:792px;" />
<div>
```

Comment: Fix your html, there is no closing div's, after you fix it it would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are not ending div tags.

```
<img>
```

can work without "/"
and to align horizontally in center use

```
<div align="center" class="pdf-pageimage-container" style="position:relative;width:792px;height:612px;"></div>
```

Comment: Ahh - forest for the trees!  That would also explain why the auto-formatter was acting all weird.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is incorrect. You are opening `<div>` tags but not closing them with `</div>`, so you are opening lots of nesting div elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can place them in a wrapper div with a fixed width and then center each of them with auto margin.

Let's say that the wrapper has an ID `wrapper` and the sub-elements all have the class `child`. In that case you can for example set the following in your CSS

```
#wrapper{
    width: 800px;
}
.child{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First off I would close the endings of the "div" tags like so  just to stay valid with your code.
2. I'll assume that these divs will stack on top of each other so add this to your "pdf-pageimage-container" css class:

   .pdf-pageimage-container {
   clear : both;
   }
3. If you want the divs to float next to each other one after another you could use this instead

   .pdf-pageimage-container {
   float : left;
   }

Hope this helps.